# How can I install Interface Addons when running WoW in Wine?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, linux, wine

So i didnt know if i should ask this question in AskUbuntu or here, but since I've seen some good answers on Wine gaming here, i figured this would be a good place.

I just recently started using Ubuntu, and for a while i used Dual Boot to play World of Warcraft.

But it runs mostly fine under Linux using Wine, but i'm a little bit confused, where on my File System the "Windows Filesystem" from Wine, where WoW is saved at, is located.

I want to use some Interface Addons, because i became quiet used to them but I dont know where to put them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you've modified the default values for your Wine and WoW install, the path should be:

```
~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/World\ of\ Warcraft/Interface/AddOns/
```

`~` being your home folder. Perhaps you won't need backslashes before spaces if you're using a graphical file explorer.

Once you've found this, there should be no differences with the Windows version. Paste your add-on folder and enable it in game.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is while running the Windows OS in Wine, you could use an addon manager ie. [**"Curse addon manager"**](http://www.curse.com/client) for WoW.

The app allows you to download UI mods or other addons for WoW directly from inside the application and it will take care of the file placement and setting up, etc.

I did the same thing back when I ran a similar windows Emulator on my mac to have mods, before I found out about the Mac client.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an addon manager for Linux (also windows and OS X), you may want to check out http://www.wowmatrix.com/.